# Different behaviour when reading from Parquet in standalone/master-slave spark-shell

Tags: scala, shell, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, parquet

Here is a snippet from a larger code I'm using to read a dataframe from Parquet in Scala.

```
case class COOMatrix(row: Seq[Long], col: Seq[Long], data: Seq[Double])

def buildMatrix(cooMatrixFields: DataFrame) = {

  val cooMatrices = cooMatrixFields map {
    case Row(r,c,d) => COOMatrix(r.asInstanceOf[Seq[Long]], c.asInstanceOf[Seq[Long]], d.asInstanceOf[Seq[Double]])
  }

  val matEntries = cooMatrices.zipWithIndex.flatMap {
    case (cooMat, matIndex) =>
      val rowOffset = cooMat.row.distinct.size
      val colOffset = cooMat.col.distinct.size

      val cooMatRowShifted = cooMat.row.map(rowEntry => rowEntry + rowOffset * matIndex)
      val cooMatColShifted = cooMat.col.map(colEntry => colEntry + colOffset * matIndex)

      (cooMatRowShifted, cooMatColShifted, cooMat.data).zipped.map {
        case (i, j, value) => MatrixEntry(i, j, value)
      }
  }

  new CoordinateMatrix(matEntries)
}


val C_entries = sqlContext.read.load(s"${dataBaseDir}/C.parquet")

val C = buildMatrix(C_entries)
```

My code executes **successfully when running in a local** spark context.

On a **standalone cluster**, the very same code fails as soon as it reaches an action that forces it to actually read from Parquet.
The dataframe's schema is retrieved correctly:

```
C_entries: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [C_row: array<bigint>, C_col: array<bigint>, C_data: array<double>]
```

But the executors crash when executing this line `val C = buildMatrix(C_entries)`, with this exception:

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at $line39.$read$$iwC.<init>(<console>:7)
    at $line39.$read.<init>(<console>:61)
    at $line39.$read$.<init>(<console>:65)
    at $line39.$read$.<clinit>(<console>)
    at $line67.$read$$iwC.<init>(<console>:7)
    at $line67.$read.<init>(<console>:24)
    at $line67.$read$.<init>(<console>:28)
    at $line67.$read$.<clinit>(<console>)
    at $line68.$read$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$anonfun$3.apply(<console>:63)
    at $line68.$read$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$anonfun$3.apply(<console>:62)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:328)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.getIteratorSize(Utils.scala:1597)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.ZippedWithIndexRDD$$anonfun$2.apply(ZippedWithIndexRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.ZippedWithIndexRDD$$anonfun$2.apply(ZippedWithIndexRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1858)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1858)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:66)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:89)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:213)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at $line4.$read$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:15)
    at $line4.$read$$iwC.<init>(<console>:24)
    at $line4.$read.<init>(<console>:26)
    at $line4.$read$.<init>(<console>:30)
    at $line4.$read$.<clinit>(<console>)
    ... 22 more
```

Not sure it's related, but while increasing the log verbosity, i've noticed this exception:

```
16/03/07 20:59:38 INFO GenerateUnsafeProjection: Code generated in 157.285464 ms
16/03/07 20:59:38 DEBUG ExecutorClassLoader: Did not load class org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$SpecificUnsafeProjection from REPL class server at http://155.198.193.158:32862
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class file not found at URL http://155.198.193.158:32862/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/expressions/GeneratedClass%24SpecificUnsafeProjection.class
```

I've tried different configurations for the standalone cluster:

- master, 1 slave and spark-shell running on my laptop
- master and 1 slave each running on separate machines, spark-shell on my laptop
- master and spark-shell on one machine, 1 slave on another one

I've started with the default properties and evolved to a more convoluted properties file without more success:

```
spark.driver.memory                4g
spark.rpc=netty
spark.eventLog.enabled             true
spark.eventLog.dir                 file:///mnt/fastmp/spark_workdir/logs
spark.driver.extraJavaOptions      -Xmx20480m -XX:MaxPermSize=2048m -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=2048m
spark.shuffle.service.enabled      true
spark.shuffle.consolidateFiles     true
spark.sql.parquet.binaryAsString   true
spark.speculation                  false
spark.rpc.timeout                 1000
spark.rdd.compress true
spark.core.connection.ack.wait.timeout 600
spark.driver.maxResultSize         0
spark.task.maxFailures             3
spark.shuffle.io.maxRetries        3
```

I'm running the pre-built version of **spark-1.6.0-bin-hadoop2.6**.
There's **no HDFS** involved in this deployment, all Parquet files are stored on a shared mount (CephFS) available to all the machines.

I doubt this is related to the underlying file system, as another part of my code reads a different Parquet file fine in both local and standalone mode.

Comment: So if you call for instance `C_entries.count` right after the read of the parquet file `val C_entries = sqlContext.read.load(s"${dataBaseDir}/C.parquet")` it also fails?

Comment: yes i can. I can even do it after the crashed executors recover. I think i remember reading something about that, that Spark didn't need to read the whole parquet file to get the count of rows in the dataframe, so no necessarily surprising that it works.

Comment: Alright - I am not aware that Spark can omit performing an action, but that doesn't mean that it isn't so ;)  I simply wanted to work out whether the problem has to do with reading the parquet file (perhaps a corrupt file or null values where you don't expect them) or if the problem is with the actual code. So if you think `count` could be misleading, then do some trivial `map` followed by, say, a `reduceByKey` and then count. It _has_ to evaluate the entire parquet file when calling `reduceByKey`. If this simple example works you will know that it has nothing to do with the parquet file.

Comment: i can't really see how it could come from the Parquet file itself as it reads fine when the code runs on a pure local spark-shell (not attached to a master). Anyway I tried it to be sure, this runs fine `C_entries.map (x => x).countByValue`, this also runs fine `C_entries.collect` but calling the `buildMatrix(C_entries)` straight afterwards crashes the executor. There must but something in the function and/or the configuration of my master slave that messes up with the Parquet file reading.

Comment: Hmm... I just tried to run the code on a small AWS cluster (running on YARN and not standalone, though) reading the parquet file from S3, and it runs just fine... Can you narrow down which part of the _buildMatrix_ causes the crash? The `map` or the `flatmap` function?

Comment: Interesting, this might suggest something fishy in my standalone configuration. According to the stacktrace, the last understandable bit of call reports going through `org.apache.spark.rdd.ZippedWithIndexRDD$$anonfun$2.apply` so I assume it in the `flatMap` (or could it be the `zipWithIndex` itself?). Did you generate your own version of the parquet file? I can make it available if you want.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105705/discussion-between-glennie-helles-sindholt-and-jopasserat).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*TL;DR*: package your code as a **jar**

For record purpose, the problem seemed to be linked to the use of a standalone cluster.

The exact same code works fine with these setups:

- spark-shell and master on the same machine
- running on YARN (AWS EMR cluster) and reading the parquet files from S3

With a bit more digging in the logs of the standalone setup, the problem seems to be linked to this exception with the class server:

```
INFO GenerateUnsafeProjection: Code generated in 157.285464 ms
DEBUG ExecutorClassLoader: Did not load class org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$SpecificUnsafeProjection from REPL class server at http://155.198.193.158:32862
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class file not found at URL http://155.198.193.158:32862/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/expressions/GeneratedClass%24SpecificUnsafeProjection.class
```

My understanding is that the `spark-shell` starts an HTTP server (*jetty*) in order to serve the classes it generates from the code in the REPL to the workers.

In my case, lots of classes are served successfully (i've even managed to retrieve some through *telnet*). However the class `GeneratedClass` (and all its inner classes) can't be found by the class server.

The typical error message appearing in the log is:

```
DEBUG Server: RESPONSE /org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/expressions/GeneratedClass.class  404 handled=true
```

My idea is that it works with master and spark-shell on the same server as they run in the same JVM so the class can be found even though the HTTP transfer fails.

The only successful solution I've found so far is to **build a jar package** and use the `--jars` option of `spark-shell` or pass it as a parameter to `spark-submit`.